# Custom ASP.NET WebAPI route not working. Action never gets hit

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api

I am trying to get a route to work in ASP.NET WebAPI and need some assistance.

This is my default GET that maps to perfectly to GetFeedbackPosts(id As string) in my api controller

```
  /api/feedbackPost/id
```

However, I also need another GET "action" or method if you will in that same api controller that is called GetFeedbackPostCategories(). I am trying to access it with the following uri:

```
/api/feedbackPost/getFeedbackPostCategories
```

The GetFeedbackPostCategories() method never gets hit,...it always hits GetFeedbackPosts()

These are my routes:

```
    RouteTable.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
        name:="DefaultApi",
        routeTemplate:="api/{controller}/{id}",
        defaults:=New With {Key .id = RouteParameter.Optional})


    RouteTable.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
        name:="MVCActionStyleApi",
        routeTemplate:="api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        defaults:=New With {Key .id = RouteParameter.Optional})
```

I am trying to target the one named "GeneralApi". However, like I said, it keeps hitting the wrong action, (the other Get action on the controller). Any Ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first route will match any URI with the form /api/something/something, so the second route won't be matched in this case.

In general, mixing "{action}" routes with non-action routes in Web API doesn't work very well. Even if you can get the routing to work, you usually hit problems with action selection.

For example, if you send a GET request for /api/feedbackPost, the action selection can't distinguish these two methods, so you'll get a "multiple matching actions" error

```
public class FeedbackPost : ApiController
{
    public HttpResponseMessage GetFeedbackPosts()

    [HttpGet]
    public HttpResponseMessage GetFeedbackPostCategories()
}
```

Depending on your exact scenario, one option is to treat "FeetbackPostCategories" as a separate resource and create a "Categories" controller, and use GET /api/categories.

Or, Web API 2 (currently in RC) supports [attribute-based routing](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2), which would let you handle this case.

Answer (score 0):

Just leave your second route and update it with default value of `action = "GetFeedbackPosts"`:

```cs
RouteTable.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
  name:="MVCActionStyleApi",
  routeTemplate:="api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
  defaults:=New With {Key .id = RouteParameter.Optional,
                      Key .action = "GetFeedbackPosts"})
```

P.S. sorry for syntax, seems it's VB.

Then, you'll be able to request the first URL

> /api/feedbackPost/id

by modified one `/api/feedbackPost/GetFeedbackPosts/id`, 
but without `id` it is possible: `/api/feedbackPost`.

Thus your second URL `/api/feedbackPost/getFeedbackPostCategories` will work originally and You can add many other **Get** actions.

But I recommend You to use attributes `[ActionName]` before declaring actions in controller to exclude requesting this evident long verbs with **get** word in name and transform to nouns like this: `/api/feedbackPost/feedbackPostCategories`.

Proof link -> [Web API Design: Crafting Interfaces that Developers Love](http://www.slideshare.net/jbellatl/web-api-13401876)